# 2D XNA C#: Texture2D Wrapping Issue

Tags: xna

Working in C#/XNA for a Windows game: I'm using Texture2D to draw sprites. All of my sprites are 16 x 32. The sprites move around the screen as you would expect, by changing the top X/Y position of them when they're being drawn by the spritebatch.

Most of the time when I run the game, the sprites appear like this:

[image: Normal sprite]

and when moved, they move as I expect, as one element.

Infrequently they appear like this:

[image: Wierd sprite]

and when moved it's like there are two sprites with a gap in between them - it's hard to describe.

It only seems to happen sometimes - is there something I'm missing? I'd really like to know why this is happening.

**[Edit:]** Adding Draw code as requested:

This is the main draw routine - it first draws the sprite to a RenderTarget then blows it up by a scale of 4:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Draw to render target
    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget);
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
    Texture2D imSprite = null;

    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, null, SamplerState.PointWrap, null, null);
    ManSprite.Draw(spriteBatch);
    base.Draw(gameTime);
    spriteBatch.End();

    // Draw render target to screen
    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

    imageFrame = (Texture2D)renderTarget;

    GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.Target | ClearOptions.DepthBuffer, Color.DarkSlateBlue, 1.0f, 0);
    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, null, SamplerState.PointClamp, null, null);
    spriteBatch.Draw(imageFrame, new Vector2(0, 0), null, Color.White, 0, new Vector2(0, 0), IM_SCALE, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
    spriteBatch.End();

}
```

This is the draw routine for the Sprite class:

```
public virtual void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, new Vector2(PositionX, PositionY), null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, Scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0.3f);
}
```

Comment: Something like this is really hard to debug. I'd try swapping the texture with a debug one, something patterned such that you can easily identify where parts of it are rendered.

Comment: One common mistake when sprites aren't moving correctly is because there's inconsistency between when you move it with .Update logic and when you move it with .Draw logic. Generally you should always avoid doing any engine logic in .Draw and only move and position things etc. in the .Update method.

Comment: @MindWorX this doesn't seem like a simple problem - It's more like the texture is rolling around the sprite rather than the sprite moving incorrectly

Comment: Can you post your draw code?

Comment: That looks like slicing. Is the sprite moving all that way in a single frame?

Comment: @Benixo I've updated the question with the draw code, thanks :)

Comment: @Blecki Sort of. When the frame is static it looks like that. If I move it downwards his body will look like it'll move up through the gap so there'll be more sprite at the top and less at the bottom.

What do you mean by slicing? 

Thanks!

Comment: Slicing is when the screen refreshes in the middle of a frame and you get half of the last frame, and half the current frame, on the screen at once. If this is how it looks every frame it's not slicing.

Comment: I don't think you should be calling base.Draw(...) right in the middle like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually resolved this issue; it was to do with a faulty graphics chipset in the computer I was developing on. A new graphics card was required.

Answer (score 1):

(If you haven't solved it already)

Two things you can do to debug this further (if my solutions are not your problem) and give us more information:

1. Use a normal SpriteBatch.Begin.  (i.e. Just have a SpriteSortMode and a BlendState.  No PointWrap (which I think may be your problem since you're scaling it.)  If that doesn't work then:
2. Comment out the Rendertarget code and render normally.  I've seen some of my Rendertargets do wonky stuff like this, so I wouldn't rule it out.

Also, @Blecki, base.Draw simply draws something tagged as a DrawableGameComponent.  All the code is doing there is drawing the rendertarget on top of any other automatic draw calls.  That shouldn't be a problem.

I would bet my money on the PointWrap, as it will "wrap" the sprite when it is scaled if it cannot scale it uniformly.

Comment: thanks, good idea, I'll give that a try later tonight. :)